# Python CGI script to scan remote HTTP Client

Tags: python, python-2.7, cgi, web.py, nmap

Im having some trouble getting this python web script to run and print out the results on a web page. It is a small project i'm toying with that will be run on a OpenWRT router.

When a wireless client connects to the access point the CGI script will run against the device's IP address retrieved from the HTTP sessions and display if any ports are open that may leave the inidividual open to some kind of attack on a public network.

I can confirm the port scan operates correctly from a wireshark packet capture.

At the minute I keep getting a CGI error stating there is an error with the Nmap syntax - though I know this works in a Python shell

the error I am getting is -

```
A problem occurred in a Python script. Here is the sequence of function calls leading up to the error, in the order they occurred.
 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/cgi-bin/test.py in ()
     20 for client in nm.scan():
     21         print('----------------------------------------------------')
=>   22         print('Host : %i' % (nm[client].all_protocols().keys))
     23 """
     24 
nm = <nmap.nmap.PortScanner object>, client = 'nmap', ].all_protocols undefined
 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/cgi-bin/build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/nmap/nmap.py in __getitem__(self=<nmap.nmap.PortScanner object>, host='nmap')

<type 'exceptions.KeyError'>: 'nmap'
      args = ('nmap',)
      message = 'nmap'
```

Here's my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
import cgi
import os
import nmap
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()  # for troubleshooting

print "Content-type: text/html"
print
print """
<html>
<head><title>Sample CGI Script</title></head>
<body>
<h3> Sample CGI Script </h3>
"""
client = cgi.escape(os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"])
print ('your IP Address is: ' + client)
nm = nmap.PortScanner()
nm.scan(client, '21')

for client in nm.scan():
    print('----------------------------------------------------')
    print('Host : %i' % (nm[client].all_protocols().keys))
"""

</body> 
</html>
 """
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

""" Nmap CGI """

import cgi
import os
from libnmap.process import NmapProcess
from libnmap.parser import NmapParser

print 'Content-Type: text/html'
print # Blank line marking end of HTTP headers

def main(target):
    """ I'm a lumberjack and i'm ok """
    nmap = NmapProcess(target, options="-T5 -p 21")
    nmap.run()
    nmap_report = NmapParser.parse(nmap.stdout)

    for host in nmap_report.hosts:
        address = host.address
        hostname = host.hostnames[0]
        ports = host.get_ports()
        ports = '<br/>'.join(["Port: %s Proto: %s<br/>" % (_id, name)
                            for (_id, name) in host.get_ports()])

        print """
        <center><hr style='margin-top:5%'>
        Hostname: {hostname} <br/> Address: {address} <br>
        Open ports: {ports}
        <hr>
        </center>
        """.format(address=address, ports=ports, hostname=hostname)

main(cgi.escape(os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"]))
```

---

**Output**

```
Content-Type: text/html


        <center><hr style='margin-top:5%'>
        Hostname: localhost <br/> Address: 127.0.0.1 <br>
        Open ports: Port: 21 Proto: tcp<br/>
        <hr>
        </center>
```